# Torquebox Jruby Rails Deploy

Tags: torquebox

I have created a Jruby rails application. I am able to deploy the application in windows server by  using torquebox deploy and able to run the application using torquebox run. But when I close my command prompt(terminal) my Torquebox server is stopping. How I can able to run the server even after closing the terminal?

Answer (score 0):

Run it as a windows service.  In windows a service can be created to run a program in the background, in a similar way to running a daemon in unix.